# Does attaching files in phpmailer Uploads them to Server?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, attachment

I'm hosting a website in a server that does not support file size more than 5 MB.

Now, my client wants to send an 8 MB file from a Form (through phpmailer that I implemented) to some e-mail.

Is it possible to send a file from the Form to an email directly without transferring the file to server?

Comment: [`addAttachment`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/fd1eba26972835ca7f89ab79dada7b1227e9c385/class.phpmailer.php#L2230) requires an existing path/file to begin with. It doesn't duplicate that file. But you would already have to have a file.

Comment: I want the file to be sent from my user 'A' to some other user 'B' through  email. The Interface would be a Form.

Comment: PhpMailer doesn't care about the form, or how the file got there. It doesn't handle the file upload. Your code must access the `$_FILES` and prepare them. Copying the temporary file is redundant however. You can just pass that to `addAttachment`. If you got POST / file size upload constraints, or a general disk space *quota*, then that's a server configuration issue. Nothing to do with PhpMailer whatsoever. -- Research whatever constraing you believe to have there. (5MB is quite an odd number to pull. So you're perhaps doing something else wrong / or misread some provider docs.)

Comment: Nice one Mario! It does indeed sound like the best solution is to find a hosting provider that's not total junk.